# Create tar from multiple folders and change folder name

Tags: bash, tar

Suppose I have a folder structure as follows:

```
/
    parent1
        child1
            1.log
            2.log
        child2
    parent2
        child3
            3.log
            4.log
        child4
    parent3
        child5
            5.log
        6.log
```

Let's say, I would like to add "child1", "child3" and "parent3", then I would like my tar to look like this:

```
result.tar.gz
    myfolder1
        1.log
        2.log
    myfolder2
        3.log
        4.log
    myfolder3
        child5
            5.log
        6.log
```

So basically, I would like to give my own names to the folders inside the tar, and lose the full path.

Is there any tar/bash magic which can achieve this?

Obviously, I could collect the contents of the selected folders into a new location with the correct structure and then tar that, but I would very much like to do it in 1 line, if possible.